# C#, Как перенести часть данных по условию из одной DataTable в другую используя LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq

Суть такова: есть две таблицы DataTable, A и B, они связаны по полю Id.

Задача:

> заполнить поле Info таблицы А из аналогичного поля таблицы B.

Можно ли это как-нибудь организовать при помощи LINQ?

Пытался сделать подобным образом, но ничего не вышло:

```cs
foreach (var rA in A.AsEnumerable() 
                join rB 
                in B.AsEnumerable() 
                on rA.Field<string>("ID") equals rB.Field<string>("ID"))     
{
    rA.Field<string>("Info") = rB.Field<string>("Info");
}
```

Comment: Ну join у вас уже есть через LINQ. Чего вам еще нужно?

Comment: Нужно что бы это работало, этот код не работает, C# так не умеет.

Comment: У вас есть 2 объекта....у них есть `Id` и `Info`... вам нужно скопировать `info` по полю `id`, верно понял?

Comment: Да, все  верно поняли.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте как-то так:

```
    dt1.AsEnumerable().Join(dt2.AsEnumerable(),
    x1 => x1.Field<string>("Id"),
    x2 => x2.Field<string>("Id"),
    (x1, x2) => new {Row=x1,Data=x2.Field<string>("Info") }).ToList().
    ForEach(row=>row.Row.SetField("Info", row.Data));
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот такой пример:

класс:

```
public class TestClass
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }

    public TestClass(int id, string value)
    {
        this.Id = id;
        this.Value = value;
    }
}
```

и собственно присвоение

```
  // тестовые данные
  var list1 = Enumerable.Range(1, 20).Select(s => new TestClass(s, $"my value is {s}"));
  // тестовые данные
  var list2 = Enumerable.Range(1, 20).Select(s => new TestClass(s, $"my value is {s + 20}"));

  // просто создаем новый объект, id и info берете с первого объекта, остальное со второго
  var sер = list1.ToList().Join(list2.ToList(), l1 => l1.Id, l2 => l2.Id, (l1, l2) => new TestClass(l2.Id,l1.Value));
```